# Is there a way to use php to extract textarea data from a site and load it to my database?

Tags: php, database, iframe, get, textarea

I'm rather new at using PHP and I've looked through all the q and a concerning extracting data with php, but it's all about specific words/data or the whole page. I just want to know if there's a code out there that allows you to extract the data from a textarea in the website (the site is in an iframe on my website) and then use the info to store into a database?

Any help at all wold be greatly appreciated. I'm SO out of the loop. It's been years. Yeah, I'm a noob, but ya gotta start somewhere.

Thanks.

Comment: iFrames are very evil for this kind of concept. Can't you use AJAX with DIVs instead?

Comment: is the website in your iFrame from the same origin or some other website?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the URL pointed to in the iframe, then you can do this with the file_get_contents command, but you will face problems on SSL sites. You can also use stream_get_contents. Something like:

```
$webpage = '';
if ($stream = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r')) {
    $webpage = stream_get_contents($stream);
    fclose($stream);
}

echo $webpage;
```

Comment: but still there is no possibility to have access on a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access an iFrame with PHP. This would only work with JavaScript. And even then only when the site within the iFrame has the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

However, what you can do is read a website with PHP with `file_get_contents(URL)`. But you won't have access to a textarea, since that happens on the client side (PHP = backend).

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX. But that's not PHP at all. It's all about JavaScript.

Try Jquery.

If you've a form like this:

```
<form>
<textarea id='my-text-area'></textarea>
</form>
```

you can do something like this:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "save-textarea-to-mysql.php",
  data: $("#my-text-area").val(),
  success: function(){
    alert('it Works!');
  }
});
</script>
```

Then in save-textarea-to-mysql.php you can store it in the DB.

Comment: the questioner asks about a textarea within an iframe

Comment: What's the deal? Can do it inside the frame.

Comment: Oh, i see. He wants to retrive the data from an external Iframe? Weird.

Comment: I thought he wanted to send it's own Textarea value independently from the entire form.